# reCaptcha v3 identifies legit users as spambots (score = 0.1)

Tags: javascript, php, web, recaptcha

I have recently implemented reCaptcha v3 in a 'contact us' page. I built it so that if a user gets any score below 0.3 for the recaptcha, his/hers form will not be sent 
and instead the user's data and the reCaptcha response  will be written in a log fiie.

so now I see that legit users (for sure, based on their forms) are getting 0.1 scores.
dose anyone have any idea what can be the problem? 
is there any way for users to prove they are not robots, using reCaptcha v3?

thank you

Comment: Did you find a solution to this in the end? I have the very same problem, at the moment it only appears to be flagging us Developers as spam after we've been making lots of requests [previously successfully]. Now, every attempt is flagged as spam (score 0.1)

My concern is if this occurs for genuine users, there's no way currently to handle this. I've tried adding multiple actions on the page [their pretty poor documentation said the more the better] to no avail.